# How to write symmetric equation?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Usually, to write a symmetric equation, I know that we'd isolate the scalar multiple (also known as t) from the parametric equation so that each may equal to one another. However, after solving a system of equations of 2 planes, I am left with this as the parametric equation and don't know how to change it to a symmetric equation:

x = 2

y = s

z = −s + 1

Any ideas?

NOTE: The two equations of the plane were (1) 2x − y + 3z − 1=0 and (2) 4x − 2y + 6z − 2    =0 if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If

$$\begin{align}
x&=2,\\
y&=s,\\
z&=-s+1,
\end{align}$$

then

$$\begin{align}
x-2&=0,\\
y&=s,\\
1-z&=s.
\end{align}$$

Comment: in this case, the symmetric equation would be y=z-1 but what would happen to the x-2=0? How would I make that part of the symmetric equation?